# Eagle Library for TI LDO

Tags: eaglecad, ldo

I am designing a development board and I need an onboard Low Dropout Voltage Regulator. There are a few which I have finalised but the problem is that I am not able to find the package for them in any of the Eagle Libraries. Here are the LDO I have finalised and the packages next to it.

1.[TPS79650](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps79650.pdf)  (6-Pin SOT-223)

2.[LP3855](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lp3852.pdf) (5-pin SOT-223)

3.[LM1117-N](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm1117-n.pdf) (SOT-223 or DDPAK/TO-263)

Kindly help me find the packages for the above LDO or suggest any equivalent LDO.

Comment: Just make the packages yourself. You will have to do this eventually. Sparkfun has a tutorial on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LP3855 component is available on SnapEDA: http://www.snapeda.com/parts/LP3855EMP-ADJ/Texas%20Instruments/view_part/, as is the LM1117 (although it's not the N variation, so not sure if it differs): http://www.snapeda.com/parts/LM1117T-ADJ/Texas%20Instruments/view_part/

Comment: I wasn't aware of SnapEDA library.  Wow, millions of parts, exports footprints to Eagle, Altium, KiCad and OrCAD, and is free.  Can't figure out their business model, but who cares.